# Git Pull Doesn't Do A Git Fetch

Tags: git, fetch, pull

My understanding has always been that `git pull` is essentially a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge ...` but I have encountered it a number of times where pulling, then comparing shows changes that aren't mine until I also do a fetch:

(on branch blob):

```
git pull origin blob
git diff origin/blob  <- shows a bunch of changes that aren't from my but were just pulled from others
git fetch
git diff origin/blob  <- shows just my changes
```

Is my understanding of pull incorrect?

Comment: This is assuming there are no remote changes between your `git pull` and explicit `git fetch` correct?

Comment: I wonder if `git fetch --all` would make a difference if used in your third step.  I wouldn't think that your second fetch would make any difference at all; that's what is confusing me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a common source of confusion, so much so that the `#git` IRC channel has a canned help text for it, called `!pull4`:

> We recommend against using 'git fetch/pull <remote> <refspec>' (i.e. with branch argument), because it doesn't update the <remote>/<branch> ref. The easy way to fetch things properly is to get everything: 'git fetch' or 'git pull' are sufficient if you have one remote; otherwise we recommend 'git fetch <remote>' (plus 'git merge <remote>/<branch>' if you wanted to pull/merge).

What's happening here is that `git pull` with no arguments does a `git fetch` on the "default remote" (typically `origin`), then `git merge`s the remote branch corresponding to your current local branch. `git pull <remote>` does the same thing with an explicitly specified remote. However, the "four-word pull", `git pull <remote> <branch>`, fetches that branch into a temporary location, `FETCH_HEAD`, *without* updating your tracking branches, and then merges `FETCH_HEAD` into your current branch.

So, by using `git pull origin blob`, you are saying "I want to merge the latest version of the `blob` branch on the remote `origin` into my current branch, without updating any of my tracking branches or fetching any other data".

If your branch merge configurations are correct (and they probably are, since `git clone` and `git checkout` try to set them up automatically), you can just `git pull` or `git pull origin` and it'll fetch everything and then merge the branch corresponding to your currently-checked-out branch. If you want more explicit control, use `git fetch` and then `git merge`. `git pull <remote> <branch>` is rarely what you want.

(The reason the `git fetch` fixes things in your example is that, after the pull, your local branch has been updated with the latest remote commits, but the tracking branch hasn't been. `git fetch` updates the tracking branch with those commits, at which point the diffs start making sense again.)

Comment: In what case do you really want the `git pull <remote> <branch>` form? +1

Comment: @BlackVegetable Honestly, I have no idea. I've never had a use for it. I guess it could be useful in workflows where you don't bother with tracking branches at all, for whatever reason?

Comment: Thanks. I did notice that git pull by itself doesn't have this issue. I sometimes want to do git pull origin whatever if I'm in a different branch but I kind of think just always doing fetch and merging from the origin/whatever branch.

Comment: The IRC help is a good idea but I thought you could manually go `git pull origin master:origin/master` and because of the colon-ed info on the right it would manually do a remote track branch?  (but they show best common practice)

Comment: Could be some caveat with that I wouldn't know.

Comment: is there any documented rationale for *why* `git pull <remote> <branch>` behaves differently?