# Git fetch with username and password

Tags: git

I want to switch to remote branch, but before that i do a fetch, so that branch get available to switch. But I want this to be done providing username/password with command itself
like `git pull "https://<un>:<pwd>"git.com/<repo>" <branch>`
pull works fine with username password but how can i used the same way for fetch command

Comment: `man gitcredentials` is the doc to start from.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no built-in way to do, but you can point `credential.helper` config at a program that will print the data on stdout.  See [man gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

You could even specify a shell command in-line with `!` but see below why that's DANGEROUS:

```bash
git -c credential.helper="!printf 'username=FOO\npassword=BAR\n'" pull REMOTE
```

This particular kludge relies on `printf` unix command, won't work on Windows.
You'll also need to quote special symbols in the password from the shell, and from printf itself (e.g. replace `%` with `%%`)...

Note that git will supply an extra `get` / `store` / `erase` argument, so for example if you said `credential.helper="!echo username=FOO"` it'd run `echo username=FOO get` and git will think the username is `FOO get`, not what you want.  `printf` happens to ignore extra args when its first "*format*" arg doesn't contain any formatting specifications like `%s`, and I relied on this not-quite-documented property here .

###### ⚠ Supplying passwords on the command line, or in env vars is INSECURE ⚠

Other process running on your computer may observe it from the list of executing processes, even if they run under a different user (detail vary by OS, `/proc/NNN/cmdline` & `/proc/NNN/environ` files on linux).

The accepted safe ways to pass credentials to another process are (1) send it on stdin (2) give it a file name (and ensure the file is not accessible by other users).  In other words, you better use (or write) a "real" credential helper...

Answer (score -3):

`git pull` does a `git fetch` anyway (followed by a merge)

So if your command worked with `git pull`, the same URL should work identically with `git fetch`.

That being said, it is a better practice to cache those credentials in a [credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/6309).

Comment: *So if your command worked with git pull, the same URL should work identically with git fetch*

Yes it should, but it doesn't. Using fetch with the repository argument does update nothing as far as I can tell while git pull with the repository argument will update the local branch but not the remote branch.

Comment: @RomanReiner OK. Can you post a new question with more details illustrating your issue? That help me (and others) for proposing a solution.

Comment: git pull does things which are conceptually different than git fetch

Comment: @user3480922 I agree: git pull does not indeed always do a git fetch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18924297/6309